# Add html tags to Struts 1.3.10 sources

Tags: java, html, jsp, tags, struts

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm stuck with Struts 1.3.10 (no, I can't try migration to a better framework since my project was given to my team with 70% completion). I'd like to add HTML tags to the Struts taglib.

I already know that for some tags (like *placeholder*) you can use jQuery but I'm not interested in that. **I want to modify Struts sources**. I've been looking for on the internet but nothing showed up that can help me. Maybe you can give me a hand with these matter.

Examples of what I want to do:

```
<html:text property="someProperty" placeholder="Hi..." length="30">
```

or

```
<html:checkbox property="choice" data-on-color="primary" data-off-color="info">
```

or add any HTML property I want.

Thanks in advance, I hope you can guide me.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to rewrite Struts 1.3.10, only you need to write the desired HTML5 form. You can convert the Struts tag:

```
<html:text property="someProperty" placeholder="Hi..." length="30">
```

to HTML5 (using some tags for the value):

```
<input type="text"
       name="someProperty" 
       value="<bean:write name="nameOfForm" property="someProperty" />" 
       placeholder="Hi..." 
       maxlength="30" 
       size="15">
```

<sub>Note: `nameOfForm` must the name of the form defined in the file `struts-config.xml`.</sub>

or (using EL):

```
<input type="text"
       name="someProperty" 
       value="${nameOfForm.someProperty}" 
       placeholder="Hi..." 
       maxlength="30" 
       size="15">
```

Check the generated HTML with Struts tags, and performs the conversion to HTML5.